# WSO2 Identity Server PostgreSQL Database Schema

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can I change PostgreSQL database schema in WSO2 IS? For default, it is `public`, but I want to change it to my custom one.

Please, help.

EXPLANATION:

I connected PostgreSQL database as primary database into WSO2 IS. First run `wso2server.bat` with `-Dsetup` parameter and all database tables was created in `public` schema of connected database.

I hope, that I can change default `public` schema to my own, for example `wso2`.

Comment: can you explain more? not clear your question.

Comment: @PradeepaWickramasinghe, see EXPLANATION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You have to modify the db scripts to use the custom schema with following line at the scripts.

`SET search_path TO wso2;`

Then set the `search_path` to include the schema you are using.

Refer the [post here](https://medium.com/@pulasthi7/configuring-wso2-products-to-use-custom-postgresql-schema-42c44c546a5c) for more detailed steps.